# In ASP.NET core Minimal API, How can I have a common function where I can supply status code and response message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net 6 minimal API. So basically I can use `Results.Ok()`, `Results.BadRequest()` etc. with a parameter for custom messages. For example `Results.BadRequest(new {error = "bad request", errorDetails = "invalid ayz param"})`. But in case of exception `Results.Problem()` I cannot pass a parameter as such.

```
app.MapGet("/", () => { 
    try
    {
        return Results.Ok(new { id = 1});
    }
    catch(Exception _)
    {
        return Results.Problem();
    }
}).WithName("/");
```

So what I want to have is an extension method such as `Results.CreateResponse(statusCode, new {details = "my details"})`.

Well `Results` is a static class but it exposes a property `IResultExtensions Extensions { get; }` to add some extension. I want to know how to use it.
So that I can do

```
app.MapGet("/", () => { 
    try
    {
        return Results.CreateResponse(200, new { id = 1 });
    }
    catch(Exception _)
    {
        return Results.CreateResponse(500, new { error = "my error"});
    }
}).WithName("/");
```

Comment: Do you really need this extension? The most common status codes are already present and some of the `Results` methods have overloads where you can specify the status code explicitly. Check again [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results?view=aspnetcore-7.0#methods) (all `Nullable<int>` parameters should be the custom status code parameters).

Comment: Try [`Results.Json(new { ... }, statusCode: 123)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.json?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-json-1(-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-system-string-system-nullable((system-int32)))).

Comment: Better to use the standard problem details

Comment: @davidfowl meaning?

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.problem?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-problem(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-problemdetails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`Results.Json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.json?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-json-1(-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-system-string-system-nullable((system-int32)))) already? Why is not working for you?

```cs
app.MapGet("/", () => { 
    try
    {
        return Results.Json(new { id = 1 }, statusCode: 200);
    }
    catch(Exception _)
    {
        return Results.Json(new { error = "my error"}, statusCode: 500);
    }
}).WithName("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to `Results.Problem()`, below is the code, I'm throwing an exception just for testing purposes.

```
    app.MapGet("/", () => {
    try
    {

        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Results.Problem("Error Message", "Instance", (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}).WithName("/");
```

Here is the response on the swagger:

[image: Swagger Response]

Answer (score 1):

[Customizing results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customizing-results)

You'll need to add an extension method to IResultExtensions.

Code:

```
public static class ResultsExtensions
{
    public static IResult DoSomething(this IResultExtensions resultExtensions, string text)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(resultExtensions);

        return new MyResult(text);
    }
}

public class MyResult : IResult
{
    private readonly string _text;

    public MyResult(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_text);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Results.Extensions.DoSomething("test");
```